# How do I disconnect a websocket in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've followed the instructions here:

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/websockets/#simple-websocket-client-example

And I'm able to open the websocket and I have streaming data coming in.

The issue is, the documentation doesn't state how to close the websocket.

I tried to do:

```
delete r from `.
```

which seems to delete environment variable representing the websocket, the stream keeps coming.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `hclose` as it is here:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/hopen/

Comment: For anyone struggling with this, the final result was `hclose r 0`, where `0` is required as the handler is an emuneration.